# For what values of $m$ and $n$ is $\int_{0}^{1} x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}\log x\ dx$ convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I cannot really understand how to prove this I know that $\int_{0}^{1} x^{m-1} (1-x)^{n-1}\ dx$ is $\beta$ function.

Comment: i think it must be $$\Re(n)>0$$ and $$\Re(m)>0$$

Comment: In the additional information I said I know $\int_{0}^{1} x^{m-1} (1-x)^{n-1}$  is beta function however, I don't know how to prove its convergence, the title consists the full question. @MrYouMath

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'd like to know the proof as I am unable to do so. If you can help?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Don't forget that $\log x\to0$ as $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near zero, the integrand is $\sim x^{m-1}\log x$. As $|\log x|=O(x^{-\epsilon})$ for small positive $x$, the integral converges near zero iff $\text{Re}(m)>0$, as for the beta integral.

Near one, the integrand is $\sim -(1-x)^n$. This converges
near one iff $\text{Re}(n)>-1$.

Comment: what about the $\log x $ present in the second case? Won't $\log x$ will be 0 then?

Comment: @ItiShree I took that into account: $\log x\sim -(1-x)$ near $x=1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks I got it now.

Comment: The result of the integration is quite beautiful (at least to me !).

Answer (score 3):

The integral
$$ B(m,n)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(m)\,\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)} $$
is convergent as soon as $\color{red}{\text{Re}(m),\text{Re}(n)>0}$, granting the integrability of $x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}$ over $(0,1)$. Under these assumptions it is a differentiable function, also because $B(\cdot,n)$ and $B(m,\cdot)$ are moments, hence log-convex functions by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}\log(x)\,dx =\frac{\partial}{\partial m}B(m,n)$$
and by [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) we get:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1} x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}\log(x)\,dx &=& \frac{\Gamma(m)\,\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}\left[\psi(m)-\psi(m+n)\right]\\&=&-\frac{\Gamma(m)\,\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(m+n)}\sum_{s\geq 0}\frac{1}{(s+m)(s+m+n)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).